# Spawning a projectile in ImpactJS

Tags: impactjs

Using the example code that came with ImpactJS, I am wondering what

> {direction:this.lastPressed}

means. The code below refers to the player entity, when the 'attack' button is pressed.

Is 'direction' a method of some sort? I am guessing from this code, it is telling the projectile which way to travel based on the entity's direction, but I can't figure out how.

```
//attack
        if(ig.input.pressed('attack')) {
            if (this.weapon == 'projectile'){
            // create a projectile
            ig.game.spawnEntity('EntityProjectile',this.pos.x,this.pos.y,{direction:this.lastPressed});
            }else{
            // we simulate a sword with a very fast moving projectile with a limited range
            ig.game.spawnEntity('EntitySword',this.pos.x,this.pos.y,null);
            }
            ig.game.sortEntitiesDeferred();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go back to basics with this and use the code for [this game](http://impactjs.com/blog/2013/08/impact-1-23-and-new-jumpnrun-example) to base mine on. This is a lot more straight-forward, especially for the first time game developer.